# Multiple parallel Tasks in C# do not improve calculation time

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

I have a complicated math problem to solve and I decided to do some independent calculations in parallel to improve calculation time. In many CAE programs, like ANSYS or SolidWorks, it is possible to set multiple cores for that purpose.

I created a simple Windows Form example to illustrate my problem. Here the function `CalculateStuff()` raises `A` from `Sample` class in power `1.2` `max` times. For 2 tasks it's `max / 2` times and for 4 tasks it's `max / 4` times.

I calculated the resulting time of operation both for only one `CalculateStuff()` function or four duplicates (`CalculateStuff1(), ...2(), ...3(), ...4()` - one for each task) with the same code. I'm not sure, if it matters to use the same function for each task (anyway, `Math.Pow` is the same). I also tried to enable or disable the ProgressBar.

The table represents time of operation (sec) for all 12 cases. I expected it to be like 2 and 4 times faster for 2 and 4 tasks, but in some cases 4 tasks are even worse than 1. My computer has 2 processors, 10 cores each. According to Debug window, CPU usage increases with more tasks. What's wrong with my code here or do I misunderstand something? Why multiple tasks do not improve time of operation?

[image: Table of results]

```cs
        private readonly ulong max = 400000000ul;

        // Sample class
        private class Sample
        {
            public double A { get; set; } = 1.0;
        }

        // Clear WinForm elements
        private void Clear()
        {
            PBar1.Value = PBar2.Value = PBar3.Value = PBar4.Value = 0;
            TextBox.Text = "";
        }

        // Button that launches 1 task
        private async void BThr1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            Sample sample = new Sample();

            await Task.Delay(100);
            Task t = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample, PBar1, max));
            await t;

            TextBox.Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

            t.Dispose();
        }

        // Button that launches 2 tasks
        private async void BThr2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            Sample sample1 = new Sample();
            Sample sample2 = new Sample();

            await Task.Delay(100);
            Task t1 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample1, PBar1, max / 2));
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample2, PBar2, max / 2));
            await t1; await t2;

            TextBox.Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

            t1.Dispose(); t2.Dispose();
        }

        // Button that launches 4 tasks
        private async void BThr4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            Sample sample1 = new Sample();
            Sample sample2 = new Sample();
            Sample sample3 = new Sample();
            Sample sample4 = new Sample();

            await Task.Delay(100);
            Task t1 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample1, PBar1, max / 4));
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample2, PBar2, max / 4));
            Task t3 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample3, PBar3, max / 4));
            Task t4 = Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(sample4, PBar4, max / 4));
            await t1; await t2; await t3; await t4;

            TextBox.Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

            t1.Dispose(); t2.Dispose(); t3.Dispose(); t4.Dispose();
        }

        // Calculate some math stuff
        private static void CalculateStuff(Sample s, ProgressBar pb, ulong max)
        {
            ulong c = max / (ulong)pb.Maximum;

            for (ulong i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                s.A = Math.Pow(s.A, 1.2);

                if (i % c == 0)
                    pb.Invoke(new Action(() => pb.Value = (int)(i / c)));
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's probably contention for `ProgressBar.Invoke()` which will post a message to the Windows event queue and wait for it to be processed. This is going to cause some major inter-thread stuttering. Try it without the `ProgressBar.Invoke()`.

Comment: With ```ProgressBar``` disabled there are timing issues anyway - it may be 19 seconds for 1 Task, 18 for 2 and 20 for 4 (please, see table with results).

Comment: Fun fact (don't ask my why): when you do `Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff(new Sample(), PBar1, max / 4));` for all calls (`new Sample()` instead of `sampleN`) then it cuts execution time down by almost half (I get 9s instead of 19s doing this). Something something cross-thread-access something I have no idea.

Comment: I cannot see the table of results, because imgur.com is blocked where I work...

Comment: You probably want `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Another thing that will be throwing a spanner in the works is that each of your awaits will also post a message into the Windows event queue, since you are awaiting from a UI thread. You'd be better off using `await Task.WhenAll()` (although even that will post a message - but at least it will only be doing it once). Essentially, you are also timing how long it takes to post messages to the windows queue and process them...

Comment: Does `await Task.WhenAll()` has any effect here? I would test it without synchronizing to the UI thread, no progressbar

Comment: Tasks work fine, it's just all the UI stuff around the calculations that messes it up: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yY5vuY

Comment: The purpose of tasks is not to run them in parallel. If you want parallel processing use Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach which are optimized for this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tasks are not threads. "Asynchronous" does not mean "simultaneous".**

> What's wrong with my code here or do I misunderstand something?

You're misunderstanding what tasks are.

You should think of tasks as something that you can do in any order you desire. Take the example of a cooking recipe:

- Cut the potatoes
- Cut the vegetables
- Cut the meat

If these were not tasks and it was synchronous code, you would always do these steps in the exact order they were listed.

If they were tasks, that doesn't mean these jobs will be done simultaneously. You are only one person (= one thread), and you can only do one thing at a time.
You can do the tasks in any order you like, you can possibly even halt one task to begin on another, but you still can't do more than one thing at the same time. Regardless of the order in which you complete the tasks, the total time taken to complete all three tasks remains the same, and this is not (inherently) any faster.

If they were threads, that's like hiring 3 chefs, which means these jobs can be done simultaneously.

---

**Asynchronicity does cut down on idling time, when it is awaitable.**

Do note that asynchronous code can lead to time gains in cases where your synchronous code would otherwise be idling, e.g. waiting for a network response. This is not taken into account in the above example, which is exactly why I listed "cut [x]" jobs rather than "wait for [x] to boil".

Your job (the calculation) is not asynchronous code. It never idles (in a way that it's awaitable) and therefore it runs synchronously. This means you're not getting any benefit from running this asynchronously.

Reducing your code to a simpler example:

```
private static void CalculateStuff(Sample s, ProgressBar pb, ulong max)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Very simply put, this job takes 5 seconds and **cannot be awaited**. If you run 3 of these tasks at the same time, they will still be handled one after the other, taking **15 seconds total**.

If the job inside your tasks were actually awaitable, you would see a time benefit. E.g.:

```
private static async void CalculateStuff(Sample s, ProgressBar pb, ulong max)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

This job takes 5 seconds **but is awaitable**. If you run 3 of these tasks at the same time, your thread will not waste time idling (i.e. waiting for the delay) and will instead start on the following task. Since it can await (i.e. do nothing for) these tasks at the same time, this means that the total processing time takes **5 seconds total** (plus some negligible overhead cost).

---

> According to Debug window, CPU usage increases with more tasks.

The managing of tasks takes a small overhead cost, which means that the total amounts of work (which can be measured in CPU usage over time) is slightly higher compared to synchronous code. That is to be expected.

This small cost usually pales in comparison to the benefits gained from well written asynchronous code. However, your code is simply not leveraging the actual benefits from asynchronicity, so you're only seeing the overhead cost and not its benefits, which is why your monitoring is giving you the opposite result of what you were expecting.

---

> 1. My computer has 2 processors, 10 cores each.

CPU cores, threads and tasks are three very different beasts.

Tasks are handled by threads, but they don't necessarily have a one-to-one mapping. Take the example of a team of 4 developers which has 10 bugs to resolve. While this means it's impossible for all 10 bugs to be resolved at the same time, these developers (threads) can take on the tickets (tasks) one after the other, taking on a new ticket (task) whenever they finished their previous ticket (task).

CPU cores are like workstations. It makes little sense to have less workstations (CPU cores) than you have developers (threads), since you'll end up with idling developers.

Additionally, you might not want your developers to be able to claim all workstations. Maybe HR and accounting (= other OS processes) also need to have some guaranteed workstations so they can do their job.
The company (= computer) doesn't just grind to a halt because the developers are fixing some bugs. This is what used to happen on single core machines - if one process claims the CPU, nothing else can happen. If that one process takes long or hangs, everything freezes.

This is why we have a thread pool. There is no straightforward real-world-analogy here (unless maybe a consultancy firm that dynamically adjusts how many developers it sends to your company), but the thread pool is basically able to decide how many developers are allowed to work at the company at the same time in order to ensure that development tasks can be seen to as fast as possible while also ensuring other departments can still do their work on the workstations as well.
It's a careful balancing act, not sending too many developers as that floods the systems, while also not sending too few developers as that means the work gets done too slowly.

The exact configuration of your threadpool is not something I can troubleshoot over a simple Q&A. But the behavior you describe is consistent with having less CPUs (dedicated to your runtime) and/or threads compared to how many tasks you have.

Comment: I appreciate that you took so much time to teach an important principle. Unfortunately, in this case, that principle doesn't really apply. Tasks created via `Task.Run()` are executed on separate threads, so their code is run simultaneously.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior [As per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8), `Task.Run()` queues a task on the threadpool. The thread pool will only spin up a new thread if the thread pool is able to do so. Additionally (while I don't think this is the case, it is a possibility in principle), additional threads are pretty much meaningless if there is no additional CPU available to run them concurrently. There is not enough information in the question to conclude exactly what the threadpool (and OS) is doing.

Comment: They DO run simultaneously. I checked it when tried to use duplicate functions ```CalculateStuff1() and ...2```. I set two breakpoints in these functions and during execution my program jumped between them.

Comment: @Perotto: If I cut half the vegetables, then half of the potatoes, then half of the meat, then the other half of the vegetables, then the other half of the potatoes, then the other half of the meat, you will see the breakpoints pinging in all three jobs, but that does not mean I was cutting multiple things at the same time.

Comment: @Flater Does this mean that creating multiple Threads instead of Tasks will solve my problem? By the way, cfg: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, 2 processors (10 cores each).

Comment: @Perotto: I'm in the process of appending to my answer, it will touch on that. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: With 20 cores, there's no reason for `Task.Run()` to not be able to find 2 or 4 available threads. If the tasks were mostly CPU-bound, there would likely be at least a measurable performance boost. But in this case most of the time is spent updating the progress bar. Using your analogy, there are 4 chefs slicing potatoes, but they're all being asked to write a journal entry every time they make a cut, and there's only one pencil shared between them.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for your answer. Can you, please, tell me, is it okay to call the same function in different threads or is it better to create function duplicates for each thread?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: The thread pool limits _can_ be changed, and the machine could be running other heavy processes at the same time (I strongly doubt that OP's 20 core machine is a personal desktop - it's likely a server that runs more than one thing). Neither you nor me can conclude anything about exactly what is happening on the machine nor how its CPUs are currently being allocated.

Comment: @Flater: I totally agree. There are a lot of variables at play, and it's often surprising how little performance gain can be seen from multithreading, even in what you'd think would be the perfect use cases for it. But I think to say that it all boils down to "Tasks are not threads" is likely missing the mark, when there's no particular reason to believe the code is not running simultaneously on multiple threads.

Comment: @Perotto: "the same function" is ambiguous. Thread safety is not something I can explain from scratch in a comment, but calling a method isn't generally the source of a thread conflict - sharing the same resources (which could be accessed via a particular method) is.

Comment: @Flater I replaced Tasks with Threads and yes, this does improve calculation time every time. Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possible reasons that you might not see the performance gains you're expecting, including things like what else your machine's cores are getting used for at the moment. Running this trimmed-down version of your code, I am able to see a marked improvement when running parallel:

```
private IEnumerable<Sample> CalculateMany(int n)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, n)
        .AsParallel() // comment this to remove parallelism
        .Select(i => { var s = new Sample(); CalculateStuff(s, max / (ulong)n); return s; })
        .ToList();
}

// Calculate some math stuff
private static void CalculateStuff(Sample s, ulong max)
{
    for (ulong i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        s.A = Math.Pow(s.A, 1.2);
    }
}
```

Here's running CalculateMany with `n` values as 1, 2, and 4:
[image]

Here's what I get if not using parallelism:
[image]

I see similar results using `Task.Run()`:

```
private IEnumerable<Sample> CalculateMany(int n)
{
    var tasks = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, n)
        .Select(i => Task.Run(() => { var s = new Sample(); CalculateStuff(s, max / (ulong)n); return s; }))
        .ToArray()        ;
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    return tasks
        .Select(t => t.Result)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: It is just an example. My original code holds billions of operations in every loop. And without the ```ProgressBar``` multiple Tasks, according to my tests, improve the calculation time only in 40% of all cases - I don't know why it works so unstable.

Comment: I realized the code I was running originally had a bug in it. I've changed my answer significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can not give you a reason other than probably something with state machine magic that is happening but this significally increases performance:

```
private async void BThr4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clear();
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    await Task.Delay(100);
    Task<Sample> t1 = Task<Sample>.Run(() => CalculateStuff(PBar1, max / 4));
    Task<Sample> t2 = Task<Sample>.Run(() => CalculateStuff(PBar2, max / 4));
    Task<Sample> t3 = Task<Sample>.Run(() => CalculateStuff(PBar3, max / 4));
    Task<Sample> t4 = Task<Sample>.Run(() => CalculateStuff(PBar4, max / 4));

    Sample sample1 = await t1;
    Sample sample2 = await t2;
    Sample sample3 = await t3;
    Sample sample4 = await t4;

    TextBox.Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

    t1.Dispose(); t2.Dispose(); t3.Dispose(); t4.Dispose();
}

// Calculate some math stuff
private static Sample CalculateStuff(ProgressBar pb, ulong max)
{
    Sample s = new Sample();
    ulong c = max / (ulong)pb.Maximum;

    for (ulong i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        s.A = Math.Pow(s.A, 1.2);

        if (i % c == 0)
            pb.Invoke(new Action(() => pb.Value = (int)(i / c)));
    }

    return s;
}
```

This way you are not keeping Sample instances that the tasks have to access in the calling function but you create the instances within the task and then just return them to the caller after the task has completed.

Comment: You still switch between UI and worker threads (by updating the progressbar) , which messes up the measurement.